# Bool method to check user input

Tags: nsexception

Hi everybody i am trying to make a boolean method that will return value depending upon the user input for the field when submit button is clicked.

```
    - (BOOL)checkuser:(NSString*)input
{
    bool result = NO;


    if ([input isEqualToString:@"test"]) 
    {
        result = YES;
    }

    else
    {
        result = NO;
    }

    return result;

}
```

And i am refrencing this method from my program as

```
else if ([Username checkuser] == YES)
    { // do something
}
```

with following warning
 'NSString' may not respond to '-checkuser'

and i am not getting why my program crashing at this point with following error.

2011-03-22 22:57:25.942 Assignment 2[824:207] -[NSCFString checkuser]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b7c050
2011-03-22 22:57:25.944 Assignment 2[824:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString checkuser]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b7c050'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00db8be9 **exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00f0d5c2 objc_exception_throw + 47
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00dba6fb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00d2a366 __*forwarding*** + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00d29f22 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   Assignment 2                        0x00002958 -[Assignment_2ViewController SubmitbuttonPressed:] + 727
    6   UIKit                               0x002c1a6e -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
    7   UIKit                               0x003501b5 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    8   UIKit                               0x00352647 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 527
    9   UIKit                               0x003511f4 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 458
    10  UIKit                               0x002e60d1 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 567
    11  UIKit                               0x002c737a -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 447
    12  UIKit                               0x002cc732 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
    13  GraphicsServices                    0x016eea36 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x00d9a064 **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 52
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00cfa6f7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00cf7983 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x00cf7240 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x00cf7161 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    19  GraphicsServices                    0x016ed268 GSEventRunModal + 217
    20  GraphicsServices                    0x016ed32d GSEventRun + 115
    21  UIKit                               0x002d042e UIApplicationMain + 1160
    22  Assignment 2                        0x00001c04 main + 102
    23  Assignment 2                        0x00001b95 start + 53
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.
(gdb)

Answer (score 1):

You're over-complicating a very simple problem:

```
- (BOOL) checkuser:(NSString*)input {
    return [input isEqualToString:@"test"];
}
```

and then to call it:

```
if ([Username checkUser:@"DONT FORGET YOUR PARAM HERE"]) {
    // Do something...
}
```

**In your example, you're not passing any parameter to your method... That's a misstake hence your error.**

Also, if you create a method returning a 'BOOL', make sure you're returning a 'BOOL' and not a 'bool'. You have to always keep in mind that the underlying types can be different, even if a bool can be evaluated to a BOOL.

Answer (score 0):

```
 else if ([Username checkuser] == YES)
```

`checkuser` is supposed to receive a `NSString*`, which you are not sending though and is the reason for error messages. So, it should be -

Assuming `someNSString` is initialized and is of type `NSString*`.

```
else if( ([Username checkuser:someNSString] ) == YES )
                           // ^^^^^^^^^^^^ Needs to be passed as the method prototype mentions so.
{
     // ....
}
```

---

```
NSString* someNSString = @"Forgot to pass this" ;
else if( ([Username checkuser:someNSString] ) == YES )
                           // ^^^^^^^^^^^^ Needs to be passed as the method prototype mentions so.
{
     // ....
}
```

Comment: `code`else if( ([Username checkuser:someNSString] ) == YES )
                          
{
     // ....
}`code`if i am doing it like this programmin crashed again

Comment: and if i do it like [ checkuser:someNSString] it says checkuser undeclared

Comment: @user671247 - I mentioned specifically that `someNSString` is of type of `NSString*` which needs to be previously declared and initialized. It is not some thing predefined.